# Ploting two y with legends

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to plot two variables in the same graph using two y axis.

My main problem is on the aesthetic part and how to put legends in the way I desire and tiles in the axis

Here is for example my code:

```
# plots for uk debt wealth inequality 
p1<-ggplot(uk, aes(x = year))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(20,250))+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks= c(1950, seq(1950,2010,10)))+
  geom_line(aes(y = debt_sm, colour="Debt"), size=1.2, na.rm = TRUE)+
  labs( y="Public Debt   [% GDP]",x = "year", title = "Public Debt and Wealth Inequality", subtitle = "United Kingdom 1950-2009")+
  scale_colour_manual("", 
                      breaks = c("Debt"),
                      values = c("black")) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA)))+
  theme_set(theme_gray() + theme(legend.key=element_blank())) +
  theme_set(theme_bw() + theme(legend.key=element_blank())) +
  theme(text =element_text(family="Bell MT"),
        #panel.background = element_blank(), # backgrounf theme 
        plot.title    = element_text(colour = "navy", size = 10), # title    setting
        plot.subtitle = element_text(colour = "firebrick4"),   # subtitle setting 
        plot.caption  =element_text(size = 6, hjust=0), # hjust 1(right), 0.5 (center), 0(left)
        legend.position = c(0.9, 0.8)) 



p2<-ggplot(uk, aes(x = year))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), sec.axis = sec_axis(~.,name = "Top 10 Wealth Shares [%]"))+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks= c(1950, seq(1950,2010,10)))+
  geom_line(aes(y = Top10_sm*100, colour="Top Shares"), size=1.2, na.rm = TRUE)+
  labs( y="Top 10% Shares",x = "year", title = "Public Debt and Wealth Inequality", subtitle = "United Kingdom 1950-2009")+
  scale_colour_manual("", 
                      breaks = c("Top Shares"),
                      values = c("navy")) +
  theme_set(theme_gray() + theme(legend.key=element_blank())) +
  theme_set(theme_bw() + theme(legend.key=element_blank())) +
  theme(text =element_text(family="Bell MT"),
        panel.background = element_blank(), # backgrounf theme 
        plot.title    = element_text(colour = "navy", size = 8), # title    setting
        plot.subtitle = element_text(colour = "firebrick4"),   # subtitle setting 
        plot.caption  =element_text(size = 6, hjust=0),
        legend.position = c(0.9, 0.9),
        legend.key = element_blank()) # hjust 1(right), 0.5 (center), 0(left)


# make gtable objects from ggplot objects
# gtable object shows how grobs are put together to form a ggplot
g1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
g2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p2))

# get the location of the panel of p1 
# so that the panel of p2 is positioned correctly on top of it
pp <- c(subset(g1$layout, name == "panel", se = t:r))

# superimpose p2 (the panel) on p1
g <- gtable_add_grob(g1, g2$grobs[[which(g2$layout$name == "panel")]], pp$t, 
                     pp$l, pp$b, pp$l)

# extract the y-axis of p2
ia <- which(g2$layout$name == "axis-l")
ga <- g2$grobs[[ia]]
ax <- ga$children[[2]]

# flip it horizontally
ax$widths <- rev(ax$widths)
ax$grobs <- rev(ax$grobs)

# add the flipped y-axis to the right
g <- gtable_add_cols(g, g2$widths[g2$layout[ia, ]$l], length(g$widths) - 1)
g <- gtable_add_grob(g, ax, pp$t, length(g$widths) - 1, pp$b)


grid.draw(g)
```

Using this the picture I get is this

[image]

**TWO SCOPES:**

1. Put a title in the right y-axis
2. Remove the box from the legend "Debt" to fit the background of the graph
3. Put another legend that reflects the second variable above the legend I already have

Can someone help me with that ?

Comment: your code looks really complicated and many steps are not necessary. Please use `dput()` to include some reproducible data. This makes it easier to help you.

Comment: Yes, true. I will try to revise. But, part of the complication is due to the ggplot which does not have an easy way to plot variables in two y axis, and what I found to be working in my case is the use of gtables. The code after ggplots, is the minimal required and taken from the suggested answers of stackflow.

Comment: I think using `sec.axis =` instead of multiple plots combined with gtables would simplify your code; [see here](https://rpubs.com/MarkusLoew/226759) for a good tutorial. Also, regarding simplifying your code, if your question is about putting a title on the y-axis, we don't need to see the code that sets titles, custom fonts, and other formatting unrelated to your question.

Comment: @msh855 your question still lacks data.

Comment: Convinced. Will try to work the tutorial suggested by @Jan Boyer with my data and see if I succeed.  Will post an update.